# Golang telnet autocomplete commands with tabs

Tags: sockets, go, telnet

How can i implement autocomplete commands with tab in telnet client (for example puTTy).

I have socket server written in go:

```
server := tcp_server.New("localhost:9999")
...
server.Listen()
```

But telnet client puTTy send me char only when i press enter, so i can't check every character to find if it match "\t" and do autocomplete commands.

Comment: you want something to interrupt the input other than the `enter` key?

Comment: Exactly, i want to send something to telnet, that forces it to send me every char pressed not only enter interrupt. I tried this:

IAC WILL ECHO IAC WILL SUPPRESS_GO_AHEAD IAC WONT LINEMODE
255  251    1 255  251                 3 255  252       34

But it doesn't works, it doesn't send any char.

Maybe i sent it wrong because i send to telnet some bytes like [255, 251... etc]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like `termbox-go` https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    termbox "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

/*
   this is a simple cli program, this keeps polling the command line argument
   until tab or Esc is pressed,
   if TAB is pressed it does a google search of the word previous to that
   and exists incase someone presses enter
*/
func main() {
    termbox.Init()
    defer termbox.Close()
    var searchString string
    for {
        ev := termbox.PollEvent()
        switch ev.Type {

        case termbox.EventKey:
            switch ev.Key {
            case termbox.KeyTab:
                meaning := getMeaningFromWeb(searchString)
                fmt.Println(meaning)
                searchString = ""
                continue

            case termbox.KeyEsc:
                panic(1)
            default:
                searchString = searchString + string(ev.Ch)
            }
        case termbox.EventError:
            os.Exit(1)
        default:
            continue
        }
    }

}

func getMeaningFromWeb(a string) string {

    cl := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.reddit.com/r/wallpaper/search.json?q="+a, nil)
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "whitespace")
    req.Header.Set("Host", "reddit.com")
    resp, err := cl.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    response, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%v", response)
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", string(response))
}
```

this is an example of using this in commandline application, if you run this application, it will accept words(on press of tab) and quit(on pressing escape). this application searches a sub reddit for wallpaper. I am printing the response to terminal. Its not perfect, there is some config( I will update as soon as I can) that needs to be set for user input to appear. Plus there is no filter as of yet to use `backspace`. You won't see what you type and you can't use backspace, but the rest of functionality does as I described.